no leading zero in hours h:mm:ss time format to convert to seconds in a derived column in SSIS
a source flat file has duration columns in :00:00 format as well as 0:00:00 format. Trying to convert to seconds when there's no leading zeros in the hours. Sample of the Source file when viewed in notepad++
enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/62SvtuBM.png)

I've tried the following to convert into seconds using a derived column:
(DT_I4)(DT_STR,8,1254)LEN(Time) == 8 ? ((DT_I4)(DT_STR,8,1254)LEFT(Time,2) * 3600) + ((DT_I4)(DT_STR,8,1254)SUBSTRING(Time,4,2) * 60) + ((DT_I4)(DT_STR,8,1254)RIGHT(Time,2)) : ((DT_I4)(DT_STR,8,1254)LEN(Time) == 6 ? ((DT_I4)(DT_STR,8,1254)SUBSTRING(Time,2,2) * 60) + ((DT_I4)(DT_STR,8,1254)RIGHT(Time,2)) : ((DT_I4)(DT_STR,8,1254)RIGHT(Time,2)))
but not getting the desired result, getting this instead

Whereas the result should be like:



Time
Time Result




1:00:00
3600


:30:00
1800


:53:14
3194




I think your expression is good except you need another case for time values with length of 7, like 1:00:00. You have 6, for values like :00:00, and 8 for values like 10:00:00, but you need one for 7 length values.
Try this:
(DT_I4)(DT_STR,8,1254)LEN(TIME) == 8 ? ((DT_I4)(DT_STR,8,1254)LEFT(TIME,2) * 3600) + ((DT_I4)(DT_STR,8,1254)SUBSTRING(TIME,4,2) * 60) + ((DT_I4)(DT_STR,8,1254)RIGHT(TIME,2)) : (DT_I4)(DT_STR,8,1254)LEN(TIME) == 7 ? ((DT_I4)(DT_STR,8,1254)LEFT(TIME,1) * 3600) + ((DT_I4)(DT_STR,8,1254)SUBSTRING(TIME,3,2) * 60) + ((DT_I4)(DT_STR,8,1254)RIGHT(TIME,2)) : (DT_I4)(DT_STR,8,1254)LEN(TIME) == 6 ? ((DT_I4)(DT_STR,8,1254)SUBSTRING(TIME,2,2) * 60) + ((DT_I4)(DT_STR,8,1254)RIGHT(TIME,2)) : (DT_I4)(DT_STR,8,1254)RIGHT(TIME,2)


Hi...It worked for me...Thank you very much!..

Hi, is there an alternative way to write the same expression using TOKEN?... (Just curious)
